# ERROR: Identical key for two renditions (Xcode 10.1, Mojave 10.14.1)

Tags: swift, xcode10, macos-mojave

I am trying to convert a macos app from High Sierra Xcode 9.x to Mojave with Xcode 10.1

I am getting an error on my Asset.xcassets.
ERROR: Identical key for two renditions

I did have some warnings on icon sizes in the Asset.xcassets folder, which i fixed. That wasn't the issue.
I have removed the Asset.xcassets folder and copied my information back in. That wasn't the issue.

I have searched and had little luck. 
This is the error (Revealed in Log)

(M)Key
    element:    Named Element
    part:       Artwork Image
    size:       (null)
    direction:  0 - Horizontal
    value:      (null)
    identifier: 795
    dimension1: 0
    dimension2: 0
    state:      (null)
    presentationState:      (null)
    previousState:      (null)
    previousValue:      (null)
    layer:      (null)
    scale:      1
    gamut:      sRGB
    target:     (null)
    appearance:     (null)

Rendition1
 TDRenditionEntry: 0x7fb08c854170

/* com.apple.actool.errors */
../MacApp/Asset.xcassets: error: ERROR: Identical key for two renditions

(M)Key
    element:    Named Element
    part:       Artwork Image
    size:       (null)
    direction:  0 - Horizontal
    value:      (null)
    identifier: 795
    dimension1: 0
    dimension2: 0
    state:      (null)
    presentationState:      (null)
    previousState:      (null)
    previousValue:      (null)
    layer:      (null)
    scale:      1
    gamut:      sRGB
    target:     (null)
    appearance:     (null)

Rendition1
 TDRenditionEntry: 0x7fb08c854170

I'm not sure how to determine which ones are identical or needless to say, what is identical? New to swift and xcode.

Comment: I just realized that the project had an filename.ico file in this folder (which is a windows icon file) I'm guessing this caused some issue. If anyone has a reason... I'd LOVE to hear :) Thanks!!

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue in Xcode 14 when I had a mixture of the old App Icon format (with all the various sizes) and a new App Icon with only the 1024x1024 size.

After changing all to the new format archiving succeeded.

Comment: do you use macOS icons? macOS doesn't support Single Size yet and I think it might be causing the same error since I can't set every set to Single Size

Comment: @mikro098 no, I experienced this in an iOS only app.

Comment: @mikro098 I have app icon with mac version, just set the iOS icon to single size, no problem for multiple size for macOS icon.

Answer (score 4):

I had this same error. I accidentally imported the same asset file for both the `3x` individual scale and the `All Scales` images in one of my image sets.

The app compiled and ran fine, but gave me this error when I trued to archive it. I didn't need both individual and single scales, so I changed the scales to individual, deleted the extra file, and that solved it.

Comment: Plus 1 -- you tipped me off to using one 1024x1024 image for both of my two app icon sets (instead of separate files in one and just the 1024 in the other).  I made a new Assets.xcassets file with a single 1024x1024 image in both icon sets.  I had a bunch of Core Data errors, too (I'm not using Core Data).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. In my case, it was because of the duplicate asset name in the asset catalog. Once, renamed the duplicate file. It got archived successfully. It is very frustrating to find out that this sort of issue is being picked up by the compiler during a normal build/run process.